# Python 2.7 - I need to open a file twice in order for the 'w' mode to be accepted

Tags: python-2.7

This script searches for a string and replaces it.

The first script works but if you notice I have to open the file for a second time and give it the 'w' mode.

On the second script I try to open the file in the same line I use "with" but it doesn't work. It complaints about

```
IOError: File not open for writing
```

Why is this happening? What am I doing wrong?  Even though I am glad the first script is working, it looks to be inefficient.

```
oldstr = 'Time'
newstr = 'TIME'
file_path = '/home/gmastrokostas/PycharmProjects/learning/file.csv'
fopen = open(file_path)
with fopen as f:
    filedata = fopen.read()
    strg = filedata.replace(oldstr, newstr)
    fopen = open(file_path,'w')
    fopen.write(strg)
    fopen.close()
```

## --------------------------------------

```
oldstr = 'Time'
newstr = 'TIME'
file_path = '/home/gmastrokostas/PycharmProjects/learning/file.csv'
with open(file_path, 'w')  as f:
    filedata = fopen.read()
    strg = filedata.replace(oldstr, newstr)
    fopen.write(strg)
    fopen.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just pass 'w' paramater as first call?
And you don't need to close the file, if you did 'with open..', it will close it anyway.

Comment: I tried it that way and it simply refuses to work :( 


    oldstr = 'Time'
    newstr = 'TIME'
    file_path = '/home/gmastrokostas/PycharmProjects/learning/file.csv'
    with open(file_path, 'rw') as f:
          filedata = file_path.read()

ttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 'w' use 'r+'. This will open file for both reading and writing.